# IN Operator equivalence in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, range, indexeddb

I want to execute this query
select * from properties where propertyCode IN ("field1", "field2", "field3")

How can I achieve this in IndexedDB
I tried this thing

```js
getData : function (indexName, params, objectStoreName) {
            var defer = $q.defer(),
                db, transaction, index, cursorRequest, request, objectStore, resultSet, dataList = [];
            request = indexedDB.open('test');
            request.onsuccess = function (event) {
                db = request.result;
                transaction = db.transaction(objectStoreName);
                objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStoreName);
                index = objectStore.index(indexName);
                cursorRequest = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.only(params));
                cursorRequest.onsuccess = function () {

                    resultSet = cursorRequest.result;
                    if(resultSet){
                        dataList.push(resultSet.value);
                        resultSet.continue();
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(dataList);
                        defer.resolve(dataList);
                    }
                };

                cursorRequest.onerror = function (event) {
                    console.log('Error while opening cursor');
                }
            }
            request.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log('Not able to get access to DB in executeQuery');
            }
            return defer.promise;
```

But didn't worked. I tried google but couldn't find exact answer.

Comment: what is objectStore? and where you define it

Comment: I have updated the code.. please check

Comment: What are you passing as params? IDBKeyRange.only() produces a range that spans only a single key. So this cursor would only ever yield one record. If you're intending for params to be a list of keys to fetch, you can simply iterate over params and issue a get() for each one.

Comment: How can I Iterate over list ? could you please write an example code .

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that IN is essentially equivalent to `field1 == propertyCode OR field2 == propertyCode`, then you could say that IN is just another way of using OR.

IndexedDB cannot do OR (unions) from a single request.

Generally, your only recourse is to do separate requests, then merge them in memory. Generally, this will not have great performance. If you are dealing with a lot of objects, you might want to consider giving up altogether on this approach and thinking of how to avoid such an approach.

Another approach is to iterate over all objects in memory, and then filter those that don't meet your conditions. Again, terrible performance.

Here is a gimmicky hack that might give you decent performance, but it requires some extra work and a tiny bit of storage overhead:

- Store an extra field in your objects. For example, plan to use a property named `hasPropertyCodeX`.
- Whenever any of the 3 properties are true (has the right code), set the field (as in, just make it a property of the object, its value is irrelevant).
- When none of the 3 properties are true, delete the property from the object.
- Whenever the object is modified, update the derived property (set or unset it as appropriate).
- Create an index on this derived property in indexedDB.
- Open a cursor over the index. Only objects with a property present will appear in the cursor results.

### Example for 3rd approach

```
var request = indexedDB.open(...);
request.onupgradeneeded = upgrade;

function upgrade(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  var store = db.createObjectStore('store', ...);

  // Create another index for the special property
  var index = store.createIndex('hasPropCodeX', 'hasPropCodeX');
}

function putThing(db, thing) {

  // Before storing the thing, secretly update the hasPropCodeX value
  // which is derived from the thing's other properties
  if(thing.field1 === 'propCode' || thing.field2 === 'propCode' || 
    thing.field3 === 'propCode') {
    thing.hasPropCodeX = 1;
  } else {
    delete thing.hasPropCodeX;
  }

  var tx = db.transaction('store', 'readwrite');
  var store = tx.objectStore('store');
  store.put(thing);
}

function getThingsWherePropCodeXInAnyof3Fields(db, callback) {
  var things = [];
  var tx = db.transaction('store');
  var store = tx.objectStore('store');
  var index = store.index('hasPropCodeX');
  var request = index.openCursor();
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
      var thing = cursor.value;
      things.push(thing);
      cursor.continue();
    } else {
      callback(things);
    }
  };
  request.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error(event.target.error);
    callback(things);
  };
}

// Now that you have an api, here is some example calling code
// Not bothering to promisify it
function getData() {
  var request = indexedDB.open(...);
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = event.target.result;
    getThingsWherePropCodeXInAnyof3Fields(db, function(things) {
      console.log('Got %s things', things.length);
      for(let thing of things) {
        console.log('Thing', thing);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Josh . but I am unable to achieve this. can you please write an example code. This would be a great help.